# Any Reason Why IsNumeric() Fails On A Number?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, isnumeric

I currently have this line of code which has been working for the past 6 months:

```
If IsNumeric(txtProductID.Text) Then
   ...do stuff
Else
   Dim msg As String = "Error!"
End If
```

All of the sudden, no matter what kind of entry is put in `txtProductID` (including plain numbers), it fails! Is there reason for me to be going crazy over this?

Comment: How does it fail? Does it return wrong values? Does it throw some kind of exception?

Comment: Fails in what way? Returning false, or throwing an error? Can you reproduce this outside of an input form? Try printing txtProductID.Text before passing it to IsNumeric, to make sure you're passing it what you think you're passing it.

Comment: thanks michael, see my answer below. i feel dumb.

Comment: I just voted to close this question to put you out of your misery.  I chose "Spam" as the reason, since there's no "Self-inflicted wound" option.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugh... i'm an idiot... thanks for your help guys, but apparently i was clearing my whole form before accepting input, so "" will never pass as "IsNumeric". Please don't look at this question again. I feel ill.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: We all make mistakes like this once in a while.  I'm just glad that explaining it here helped you track it down.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of a shot in the dark, but one thing to watch for is that maybe someone wrote a private method called IsNumeric within the same class.  Are you sure that the code above is executing Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsNumeric()?  If you put your cursor on IsNumeric and hit F12 where does the definition point to?

Comment: i'm the only one developing and i haven't written another IsNumeric method... thx tho

Answer (score 2):

Try `Trim()`ing the string before passing it into the function. In addition, rather than using a VB-specific function like `IsNumeric`, you might try an approach like this:

```
Dim input as Integer

If Integer.TryParse(txtProductID.Text, input) Then
    ....do stuff with input
Else
    Dim msg as String = "Error!"
End if
```

If your number is a decimal number, there are corresponding functions on `Double` and `Single` as well.

As to the particular reason that `IsNumeric` is failing, I couldn't tell you. I can tell you, though, that I've always found it helpful to stick to BCL-compliant functions that are language-agnostic rather than language-specific, like `IsNumeric`, `Str`, etc.